# What Precisely is an "n-fold covering space"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

The problem I am working on asks the following: Explicitely construct a 3-fold covering of $S^1\vee S^1$. The question I have, however is more general than this one. I have seen questions similar to this before, but I have never understood exactly what is meant by an "n-fold" covering of a space. Is there a precise definition and intuitive understanding of what is meant by this?

Comment: The covering space consists locally of $n$ copies of the covered space. So the fiber $\pi^{-1}(x)$ has $n$ elements for each $x \in X$ if $\pi: Y \to X$ is an $n$ fold covering. Over each point lie $n$ points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space

Comment: Presumably you've seen a definition of "covering space" and you're not just trying this problem at random. What aspects of the definition are unclear to you? (Or maybe a different question: if you haven't seen a definition, why are you working on this problem?)

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with covering spaces. The "n-fold" aspect is what is strange to me. This term has not shown up in any of my topology classes but it is in some practice problems I am attempting. If I understand what @psl2Z is saying, then the preimage of any element under the covering map would have exactly $n$ elements. So, for example, the universal cover of the circle would be "infinite fold" so to speak. Is this correct?

Comment: I guess that you are supposed to find a connected covering space of $X= S^1 \vee S^1$. Otherwise take $X \times \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with "degree" terminology? If so, an $n$-fold covering space is synonomous with a covering space of degree $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that a covering map $p : E \to B$ is a continuous surjection such that each $b \in B$ has an evenly covered open neighborhood $U \subset B$. This means that $p^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} V_\alpha$ with pairwise disjoint open $V_\alpha \subset E$ which are mapped by $p$ homeomorphically  onto $U$. The $V_\alpha$ are called sheets over $U$. If $A$ is a finite set with $n$ elements, we say that there are $n$ sheets over $U$.

$p $ is called an *$n$-fold covering* if each evenly covered $U$ has exactly $n$ sheets over it. It is easy to see that this is equivalent to all fibers $p^{-1}(b)$ with $b \in B$ having $n$ elements.